# Prevent bootstrap navbar from resizing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I took the following bootstrap navbar...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The problem I have with this navbar is that when the screen is made smaller, the nav bar changes the way it is arranged

Before resize...
[image]

After resize...

[image]

How do I prevent bootstrap from re-arranging the nav bar? What attributes should I add/delete to ensure is always looks like the first picture. Overflow is allowed, I just need to ensure it keeps its shape.

Comment: Well, I don't know exactly what is your problem, but I had issues with the bootstrap navbar using `container-fluid`, try using only the class `container` and see what happens.

Comment: @RodrigoAraújoValente My problem is that I want the nav bar to remain a fixed sized all the time, even when the window is resized. I tried changing it to `container` but it continues to do the same thing

Comment: Did you tried to wrap the navbar inside a `div` with `container` as class?

Comment: @RodrigoAraújoValente I just tried that and it still changes the layout of the nav bar when resizing

Comment: @RodrigoAraújoValente Never mind I think you are right, if I surround it with a div and give it a width it should work

Comment: @RodrigoAraújoValente still does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figure it out, I changed...

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
```

...to a regular ul instead of one pre-define by bootstrap, so I changed it to...

```
<ul class="nav">
```

after that it was pretty simple, I floated each `ul` left so that they would be aligned horizontally. Then I placed them all inside a div with a fixed width to prevent them from collapsing.

Answer (score 1):

Open your debug tools you can see there is many media queries `@media (min-width: 768px)` style rules, these rules only work when screen width larger than 768px. So when you resize the screen size the navbar style changes.

If you want to keep the style on all screen size just modify these media queries to make these style rules work on all screen size.